# image array javascript automated

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm doing some code with changing images in an array, I've got to the point where the images change automatically but I want to get different times between the images as they change. I am writing the code in Dreamweaver.

Here is the code as it is now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img src="image1.png"   width="74" height="208" id="image1">
<br>
<button onclick="clearInterval(MyVar)">Stop Sequence</button>

<script>

MyVar = setInterval(ChangeImages, 1000)

function Start() {
myVar = setInterval(ChangeImages, 1000)
}


var Images = ["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"];


var image = document.getElementById("image1");




function ChangeImages()
{
    if (image1.src.match(Images[0]))

     {
        image.src = Images[1];

    } else if (image1.src.match(Images[1]))

     {
        image.src = Images[2];
    } else if (image1.src.match(Images[2]))

     {
        image.src = Images[3];
    } else if (image1.src.match(Images[3]))

     {
        image.src = Images[0];

    }
}
</script>

<br>

<Button onclick="Start() ">Resume</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what is the current issue ?

Comment: What is `different times`, how is that supposed to be set?

Comment: Nice story. Did you have a question?

Comment: I want to have different times between images as they change but I wanted some help on how to do that.

Comment: I want it so as image 1 goes to image 2 there is a 2 second delay for example then between 2 and 3 there is a 5 second delay for example, at the moment there is a 1 second delay between each image change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the number of seconds every time you could use setTimeout instead of setInterval and then do a callback at the end of ChangeImages. And use a random number generator to get the amount of milliseconds. In the example below I set it to 1000, 2000 or 3000 milliseconds.

```
<img src="image1.png"   width="74" height="208" id="image1">
<br>
<button onclick="clearInterval(myVar)">Stop Sequence</button>

<script>

function Start() {
   myVar = setTimeout(ChangeImages, randomInterval(1,3));
}
var Images = ["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"];
var image = document.getElementById("image1");
function randomInterval(min,max)
{   var number = (Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min))*1000;
   console.log(number);
    return number;
}

function ChangeImages(){
    if (image1.src.match(Images[0])){
        image.src = Images[1];
    }
    else if (image1.src.match(Images[1])){
      image.src = Images[2];
    }
    else if (image1.src.match(Images[2])){
      image.src = Images[3];
    }
    else if (image1.src.match(Images[3])){
        image.src = Images[0];
    }
    Start();
}
</script>

<br>

<Button onclick="Start() ">Resume</button>
```

**EDIT**

```
function Start(timeout) {
   myVar = setTimeout(ChangeImages, timeout);
}
var Images = ["image1.png", "image2.png","image3.png","image4.png"];
var image = document.getElementById("image1");

function ChangeImages(){
    if (image.src.match(Images[0])){
      image.src = Images[1];
      Start(1000);
    }
    else if (image.src.match(Images[1])){
      image.src = Images[2];
      Start(2000);
    }
    else if (image.src.match(Images[2])){
      image.src = Images[3];
      Start(3000);
    }
    else if (image.src.match(Images[3])){
      image.src = Images[0];
      Start(4000);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I wanted a set time between each image so it is the same each rotation of images

Comment: Then pass a parameter into the Start function and call it in the conditional statements. See edit on my post.

Comment: That worked great thank you, would you by any chance have an idea on how to make the second image flash on and off before it changes?